# Change activity theme and logo from fragment, attached to android.R.content

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have some activity in my app. It has theme             `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"`
in AndroidManifest.xml. This activity is a container for a fragment, and it only has `<fragment>` tag in it.
So, I start another fragment from first with this code:

```
Fragment newFragment = new WelcomeStep2Fragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            transaction.commit();
```

So, In the second fragment I want to display ActionBar. I has my own theme

```
<style name="AppThemeColoredActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
```

But when I write

```
getActivity().setTheme(R.style.AppThemeColoredActionBar);
    getActivity().getActionBar().setLogo(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_back_on_action_bar));
```

it doesn't work. However, I understand that this code could not work. So, is there a way to change Activity style and logo from the second fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way. Because
*Set the base theme for this context. Note that this should be called before any views are instantiated in the Context (for example before calling setContentView(View) or inflate(int, ViewGroup)).*
( [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html#setTheme(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html#setTheme%28int%29) )

Comment: Thanks. I changed theme of activity and used getActionBar().show() and hide()